# auto numbering and texting in equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

Is it possible to write few equations, number them automatically, and also describe the equations with some text?

I am unble to write some text in the `\begin{equation}` part

This is my case

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Description of the equation 1
                         eq1             (1)
Description of the equation 2
                         eq2             (2)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Edit after applying the solutions below -

the additional problems are all equations should be aligned and all texts should be aligned and if possible numbering can be controlled / reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways for comparatively short descriptions (or comments, or …) *inside* equations, with the `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` (the latter from `mathtools`), or with `\text` in the blast column of a `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{align}
  \intertext{Description of equation 1}
  E & = mc² \\
  \intertext{Description of equation 2}
  E & = h\nu
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{Description of equation 3}
  E & = mc² \\
  \shortintertext{Description of equation 4}
  E & = h\nu
\end{align}

\begin{flalign}\setcounter{equation}{0}
  & & E &= mc² & & \text{\footnotesize Description of equation 1}\\
  & & E &= hν& & \text{\footnotesize Description of equation 2}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. is it possible to left align the \intertext so that the text aligns with the main body. Currently it is misalgined with the main body when I compile your code. Also, can you please update the answer with equation 5 and 6 to be reset to numbers 1 and 2

Comment: @infoclogged: I've reset the equation counter (but normally, numbering is fully automatic). As to your misalignment with `\(short)intertext`, this most probably comes from something in your code: as you can see in the update, the text begins at the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put the descriptions outside the equation environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Description of the equation 1
\begin{equation}
                         E=m\,c^2
\end{equation}                       
Description of the equation 2
\begin{equation}
                         E=h\,\nu
\end{equation}
This equation has no counter
\begin{equation*}
                         F=E-T\,S
\end{equation*}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
Now we start at 1 again
\begin{equation}
                         F=m\,a
\end{equation}
But I cannot recommend to reset the equation number.
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Added more lines and output:

[image]

Comment: the numbering should be continous. wouldnt it mark 1 on both the equations?

Comment: @infoclogged No. Please just compile the code.

Comment: cool, compiled and works. But how do I reset the numbering. Not all the equation needs numbering. The following equations should start again with 1. Does it fit in the context of the asked question or should I ask a new one?

Comment: @infoclogged Please see the update. Note, however, I cannot recommend to reset the equation number.

Comment: vertical spacing is very peculiar -- equations should be evenly spaced and they're not.  unfortunately, i'm not able to investigate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Well, this is what the above MWE gives me both with `xelatex` and `pdflatex`.  I'm using the most recent TeXLive distribution on a Mac. It would be interesting to see what you got.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, I understand your question

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{Description of the equation 1} \nonumber\\
    E &= mc^2 \\
    \text{Description of the equation 2} \nonumber\\
    E &= h\nu
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This misaligns the text with the texts outside \align. The answer from @marmot suits best. Thank you.